# JSON file how to remove unwanted characters

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy

so I scraped some data into a JSON file format but there are some unwanted characters in the saved data
for example:

*"quote_text": "\u201cThe world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.\u201d",
"author": "Albert Einstein",
"tags": [
"change",
"deep-thoughts",
"thinking",
"world"*

So how can I remove these **\u201c**  type characters from the file in python

Comment: `'\u201c'` and `'\u201d'` are left and right quotation marks - the "curly quotes" used by MS Word.  If you were to do `print(your_json['quote_text'])` you would see them as quotation marks rather than their escaped representation.

Comment: This `print(' '.join(data['quote_text'].split()))` should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume dictionary as d. As I can see, there are different unicode characters like **\u201c** , **\u201d**. If you want to remove all Unicode characters at once, you can do something like this:

**one liner code:**

```
d['quote_text'].encode("ascii", "ignore").decode('utf-8')
```

**Explanation in detail:**

The below one line code remove all the unicode characters and will return value in bytes.

```
remov_unicode_char = d['quote_text'].encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

Now, in order to convert into string, you can decode it.

```
convert_str =  remov_unicode_char.decode("utf-8")
```

Now, you can check the result by printing it.

```
print(convert_str)
```

**output:**

```
The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked! Can you accept the answer in that case?

Comment: Done.. sorry i am new to stackoverflow... didn't know there was such an option

Comment: @Sherlock_oms, Looks like you have accepted other answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace method:**

If you have only 1 or 2 characters to remove I suggest that you use the string `.replace()` method:

An example can be on the quote_text key

```
your_dict['quote_text'].replace('\u201c','')
```

**Regex:**

If you are struggling with multiple characters I suggest you dive into Regex

**More:**

If you wish to apply your function to the entire dictionnary values you can use dict comprehensions:

```
d2 = dict((k, f(v)) for k, v in d1.items())
```

`d1` being your original dictionnary and `f` your function.

In our example it would be:

```
d2 = dict((k, v.replace('\u201c','')) for k, v in d1.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove multiple characters you can use a list to indicate what letters to remove:

```
text = '{ "work": "\u201cfun\u201c", "foo": ["bar", "baz"] }'
remove_chars = ['u201c', 'b', 'f']
new_text = ''.join([ch for ch in text if ch not in remove_chars])
```

To replace unwanted characters make a dictionary to hold the substitutions then make the changes:

```
subs = {
  '\u201c': "'",
  'z': 't'
}
text = '{ "work": "\u201cfun\u201c", "foo": ["bar", "baz"] }'
letter_list = [(subs[ch] if ch in subs else ch)  for ch in text]
new_text = ''.join(letter_list)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. just that wont it be a lengthy process if a lot of unwanted characters are to be removed

Comment: You will have to iterate over the original text and for each char in the text make a constant time look-up in the subs dictionary.  Finally, joining the chars in letter_list into a single string is also a linear operation.  So, the final performance of the code would be O(n) where n is the length of the text string (this dominates the other steps in terms of big O performance).  What might be a concern is the amout of memory used if text is large since a second copy of the text is created in letter_list.  If memory is a concern for you there is probably a way to perform the swaps in-place.